# Update database table without uploading a file while using a MultiPart Form - JavaEE, Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, servlets

I have a servlet which is responsible for enabling a user to update a reports table and upload a report at the same time. I have written code that enables a user upload a document and also be able to update the table with other details e.g date submitted etc.
However not all the times will a user have to upload a document. in this case it should be possible for a user to still edit a report's details and come back later to upload the file. i.e the user can submit the form **without** selecting a file and it still updates the table. 
This part is what is not working. If a user selects a file and makes some changes. The code works. If a user doesn't select a file and tries to submit the form, it redirects to my servlet but it is blank. no stacktrace. No error is thrown. 
Below is part of the code I have in my servlet:

```
if(param.equals("updateschedule"))
                {

                    String[] allowedextensions = {"pdf","xlsx","xls","doc","docx","jpeg","jpg","msg"};
            final String path = request.getParameter("uploadlocation_hidden");
                    final Part filepart=request.getPart("uploadreport_file");

                    int repid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("repid_hidden"));
            int reptype = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("reporttype_select"));
                        String webdocpath = request.getParameter("doclocation_hidden");
            String subperiod = request.getParameter("submitperiod_select");
            String duedate = request.getParameter("reportduedate_textfield");
            String repname = request.getParameter("reportname_textfield");
            String repdesc = request.getParameter("reportdesc_textarea");
            String repinstr = request.getParameter("reportinst_textarea");
            int repsubmitted = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("repsubmitted_select"));
            String datesubmitted = request.getParameter("reportsubmitdate_textfield");
            final String filename = getFileName(filepart);                
            OutputStream out = null;
            InputStream filecontent=null;
                    String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, filename.length());
                     if(Arrays.asList(allowedextensions).contains(extension))
                     {
                         try
                         {
                             out=new FileOutputStream(new File(path+File.separator+filename));
                 filecontent = filepart.getInputStream();
                 int read=0;
                 final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                 while((read=filecontent.read(bytes))!=-1)
                    {
                   out.write(bytes,0,read);             
                    }
                             String fulldocpath = webdocpath+"/"+filename;
                             boolean succ = icreditdao.updatereportschedule(repid, reptype, subperiod, repname, repsubmitted,datesubmitted, duedate,fulldocpath, repdesc, repinstr);
                             if(succ==true)
                             {
                                 response.sendRedirect("/webapp/Pages/Secured/ReportingSchedule.jsp?msg=Report Schedule updated successfully");

                             }

                         }
                         catch(Exception ex)
                         {
                          throw new ServletException(ex);
                         }



                     }
```

I'm still teaching myself javaee. Any help will be appreciated. Also open to other alternatives. I have thought of using jquery to detect if a file has been selected then use a different set of code. e.g

```
if(param.equals("updatewithnofileselected"))
{//update code here}
```

but I think there must be a better solution. Using jdk6, servlet3.0.

Comment: Can you share the HTML/JSP snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(request, 500000000, false, false, "UTF-8");
  Part part;
   while ((part = parser.readNextPart()) != null) {
      if(part.isParam()){
          if(part.isFile()){
              if(part.getName().equals("updatewithnofileselected")){
                   //update code here.
              } else if(part.getName().equals("updateschedule")) {
                   //updateschedule
              }
          }
    }
 }
```

I used this one when I am using Multipart-form and it's working fine.